# Difference between [(a and b) in c] and [a in c and b in c]

Tags: python

Hi all I am trying to solve a problem described in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYcFW.jpg). My attempt of solving it is to render a-h to 1-8 then to check for every piece of chess if diagonal tiles one line below are filled with another chesspiece, referred to as "pawns". I am having no problem with the code except with the usage of and in if-clauses. What is the difference between 1)if (a and b) in c and 2)if a in c and b in c? The latter is giving me the desired results but I am curious why 1 isn't working and how it is interpreted by the machine.

Also, is it possible to do an exclusive or in if-clauses in python? I have to consider both the cases of 1 pawn and 2 pawns available and thus is considering using and and or, but I realized that or is not exclusive in python. (Yes,after the and part is run, cases of 2 pawns available will be eliminated and thus an ordinary or is okay, but I am just curious about the way to implement it)
In addition, I would be really grateful if you can proffer some comments on the elegancy, idiomaticness and efficiency (processing speed) of my code. I know it is kind of crude and there are so many ways to make it more succinct, but to begin with, I am not even aware of the tools (syntactic sugar and such) available and I will really appreciate it if you can advise me on how to pick up the tools systematically (such as how to give order to a-h (a is to the left of b, etc.) without converting them to numbers, which have built-in order)

My code is as follows, thank you.

```
def safe_pawns(pawns: set) -> int:
    pawns=list(pawns)
    verifier=0
    pawns_num=[]
    for element in pawns:
        element_list=list(element)
        letter={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,"f":6,"g":7,"h":8}
        element_list[0]=letter[element_list[0]]
        element_list[0]=str(element_list[0])
        element_num=element_list[0]+element_list[1]
        pawns_num.append(element_num)
        print ()
    print (pawns_num)
    for i in range(len(pawns)):
        first_item=pawns[i][0]
        second_item=pawns[i][1]
        first_item_value=int(letter[first_item])
        pawns_num_check=str(first_item_value)+second_item
        print (pawns_num_check)
        second_item_checker=str(int(second_item)-1)
        first_item_checker1=str(first_item_value-1)
        first_item_checker2=str(first_item_value+1)
        converted_pawn1=first_item_checker1+second_item_checker
        converted_pawn2=first_item_checker2+second_item_checker
        if (converted_pawn1 and converted_pawn2) in pawns_num:   #########
            verifier+=1
            print (pawns[i],converted_pawn1,converted_pawn2)
        if (converted_pawn1) in pawns_num and (converted_pawn2) in pawns_num:
            print (pawns[i],converted_pawn1,converted_pawn2)**
    return verifier
safe_pawns({"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"})
```

Comment: `(a and b in c)` means check if `a` is truthy and if `b in c` is truthy.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response! This site is truly powerful! Is there a way for me to not type the in pawns_num part twice?

Answer (score 5):

`(a and b in c)` means check if `a` is truthy and if `b in c` is truthy.

You can use

```
a in c and b in c
```

or

```
all(x in c for x in (a, b))
```

which for your case would be something like

```
if all(x in pawns_num for x in (converted_pawn1, converted_pawn2)):
```

Comment: Super lucid and rapid, Kudos!